# WPF - Center ContextMenu under button

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I am trying to center a ContextMenu under a button. I am attempting to set the VerticalOffset property based on the height of the ContextMenu so that the top of the menu is always in the same place regardless of the number of items. I cannot seem to get the height of the menu (probably because it has not been drawn yet?). My code is below, How can I go about getting the height of the ContextMenu?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button PopUpButton = (sender as Button);
    PopUpButton.ContextMenu.IsEnabled = true;
    PopUpButton.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = PopUpButton;
    PopUpButton.ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Center;
    PopUpButton.ContextMenu.VerticalOffset = ((PopUpButton.ContextMenu.Height / 2) + 25);
    PopUpButton.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to center horizontally and place the `ContextMenu` under the `Button` you will have to bind the `VerticalOffset` to `ContextMenu`'s `ActualHeight` and to use a `Converter` that will calculate the desired vertical offset. You can pass the `Button`'s height as `ConverterParameter` to make it more generic.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button PopUpButton = (sender as Button);
        PopUpButton.ContextMenu.IsEnabled = true;
        PopUpButton.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = PopUpButton;
        PopUpButton.ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Center;

        Binding b = new Binding("ActualHeight")
        { 
            Source = PopUpButton.ContextMenu, 
            Converter = new HeightToOffsetConverter(), 
            ConverterParameter = PopUpButton.ActualHeight,
        };

        PopUpButton.ContextMenu.SetBinding(ContextMenu.VerticalOffsetProperty, b);
        PopUpButton.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }

    public class HeightToOffsetConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double popupHeight = (double)value;
            double buttonHeight = (double)parameter;

            return popupHeight / 2 + buttonHeight / 2;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
    }
```

You also can (and in my opinion you should) set this binding from XAML.

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse. Setting the placement mode to Bottom does move the ContextMenu to the bottom however, it is not centered under my button. I need to have the menu centered under the button. In order to use PlacementMode.Bottom, I would then need to know the width of the ContextMenu in order for it to be correctly centered.

Comment: Many thanks that work like a charm. I'm pretty new to WPF and binding so I really do appreciate the assistance.